# sprintf concatenated arguments: sprintf ( a+b, "")

Tags: c++, c, printf

Moving some code from sprintf to snprintf  -
stumbled accross this weird occurence:

```
sprintf(buf+strlen(buf), "ypasZ%c%c", iItem, val);
```

I'm not understanding what is going on there: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/ is not helping.
Is the first argument (the write to location) being "incremented" by its size? 
=> does that mean the location being written isn't buf but is buf incremented by its size? 
Or is it pre-setting the position of the write block to that of the existing string in buf, so  as to APPEND the text?

Comment: Did you add those `**` characters?  I took them out, since they're (presumably) not part of the code.

Comment: Consider `strcpy(buf+strlen(buf), "foo");` it's a poor-man's append...  Could be handy if building with multiple print statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it appends.  The first argument to sprintf is the address (pointer) where it will write the result.

If buf is a char array, the compiler (in cases like this) will treat it like a pointer.  And adding to it will increase the address.  Adding the length what is there will point to the current end of the string.

Essentially the first parameter says `address of string plus length of string that is there`, giving the address of the end of the string, rather than the beginning, so the sprintf command will write its result right to the end of the current string.

Comment: should a correct port to sprintf() then be "SnPrintf(buf+strlen(buf), **DEF_BUF_SIZE-1**, "YpasZ%c%c", iItem, val);" or "SnPrintf(buf+strlen(buf), **DEF_BUF_SIZE-1 - strlen(buf)** , "YpasZ%c%c", iItem, val);" or something else?

Comment: @PierreJohnson - `DEF_BUF_SIZE-1` will not do.  You need to take the buffer size, minus (`(buf + strlen(buf)) - p`), where `p` is the start of the allocation (might be the same as `buf`, but it's not clear from your example.)

Comment: Pierre: yes, a correct port to snprintf will need to subtract the strlen() from the buffer size as you pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

> Or is it pre-setting the position of the write block to that of the existing string in buf, so as to APPEND the text?

Yes, that's what it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument is a pointer to an area where `sprintf` should write the formatted string. `buf + strlen(buf)` means address of the terminating NULL-character (`'\0'`). `sprintf` just writes into memory starting from that NULL-character thus continuing the string in `buf`.

Answer (score 0):

What this means is that buf is probably defined as an array of size n, `char buf[n]`.  Use of `strlen(buf)` is necessary because it would then return a pointer to the end of the string in `buf`, thus appending to it.